# Possible to retrieve Twitter topics that were trending on a particular date?

Tags: python, facebook, twitter, trending

I would like to be able to call a function, in any language (preferably Python :)), where the parameters I pass in are simply a date, or date range, and I get returned a list of the topics that were trending on Twitter (or any other social media) on these dates.

Is it possible to do this? How can I do this if so?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible through the official 1.1 twitter API, which only provides currently trending topics, but http://twend.it archives trending topics on twitter. You may be able to scrape them or send an email asking if they have an API.